# Event listner not listening to scroll event in Next JS

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to update the state and show shadow in nav if user scrolls but it's not listening to the event. 
 i'm using nextJS 13 and tailwind css.

```
const [shadow, setShadow] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleShadow = () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
      setShadow(true);
    } else {
      setShadow(false);
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleShadow, true);
  };
  return window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleShadow);
}, []);
```

in my div

```
<div
  className={
    shadow
      ? "fixed left-0 top-0 w-full z-10 ease-in duration-300 bg-[#112240] shadow-xl"
      : "fixed left-0 top-0 w-full z-10 ease-in duration-300 bg-[#112240]"
  }
>
other code
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code comes from the fact that you are initializing the event listener inside your `handleShadow` function, so simply moving it out of the function's body should do the trick.

```js
const [shadow, setShadow] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleShadow = () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
      setShadow(true);
    } else {
      setShadow(false);
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleShadow, true); //moved it out the function's body
  return window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleShadow);
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
const handleShadow = () => {
  if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
    setShadow(true);
  } else {
    setShadow(false);
  }
};
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleShadow);
 }, []);
```